# the css file doesn't work when in the Django app

Tags: python, html, css, django

when i use static file in my django app,i found a strange problem : that when i use body{  } in the css file can change the body's attributes ,when i use the div's id or class name ,the css file doesn't work on the div's attributes like this:

the base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load staticfiles %}

<html lang="zh-CN">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>{% block title %} Food {% endblock title %}</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "style/index.css" %}" media="screen"/>

</head>
 <body>
  <div class="sidebar">
  {% block sidebar %}

      {% endblock %}
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      {% block content %}
       <i>Delicious</i>
      {% endblock %}
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the index.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %} Food title{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}

<div class="body-head">
</div>

<div class="body-middle">
</div>

<div class="body-foot">
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

the index.css:

```
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: brown;

}
.sidebar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: seagreen;
}
.body-head {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: sandybrown;
}
```

only the body{ }can be effect.and others like .sidebar{ } and .body-head{ } do no effect.

Comment: check if the stylesheet url is properly points to the css file

Comment: thank you very much.it's just because i forget to full the <div> with content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sidebar` block and `.body-head` div are empty.

Is this your whole page or just an example?

If you can see body styles, I suppose the css file is well referenced.

Comment: i am so sorry that i am not familiar  with the <div> enough to let the <div> be empty. thank you very much